# I just upgraded to Mountain Lion. Now I can't share files with the Snow Leopard on my network

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, file-sharing

Before the upgrade, I could pull files from the other laptop on to mine with apple file sharing. Now I can't see any machines in the network view. How can I pull files from the Snow Leopard laptop onto my Mountain Lion laptop?
Steps I've taken:

1. Files were put into the snow leopard's shared folder
2. On the mountain lion laptop, opened Finder and looked in Network. There are no computers listed.

Comment: I tried the afp idea and I can connect from MacBookPro (10.8) to iMac (10.6). When I try to drag a file over, it asks for password (of the MBP account, not the iMac) and then says file exists: overwrite, keep both copies... If I say overwrite, it creates a zero MB file. Never before did it ask for my home password. Oh- if I click "keep both" then it goes into a loop creating many many zero size files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some troubleshooting steps to take:

1. Open the **Sharing Preferences** on the Snow Leopard Mac, and make sure that File Sharing is checked. Then click **Options…*** and make sure *Share Files and Folders using AFP* is checked.
2. On the Mountain Lion Mac, open Finder and click **Go → Connect to Server…** (or press ⌘K). In the server address box, enter `afp://` followed by the IP address of the Snow Leopard Mac, then click **Connect**.

   - If you don't know the IP, you can find it by using Network Utility on the Snow Leopard Mac.
3. If that still doesn't work, open **Terminal** on the Mountain Lion Mac, and enter `ping` followed by a space and the IP of the Snow Leopard Mac.

   - If successful, you should see output like this:

     ```
     64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.249 ms
     64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.207 ms
     ```

     In which case, there's something wrong with the file sharing set up.
   - If it's not successful, you'll likely get `Request timeout` errors, and it's a network issue.

Try those steps and post the results, and I'll update my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: Ok, using afp://<ip address> worked. Thank you! Shouldn't they have just been able to find each other via the magic of bonjour/magic/rounded corners?

Comment: Yes, emphasis on *should*. Bonjour gets wonky sometimes, although in my experience it usually resolves itself. You could try [restarting the Bonjour service](http://linuxtoosx.blogspot.ca/2011/10/restart-mdnsresponder.html), or use [this Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com) to see if the service is showing up at all.